# iOS Unload a View Rather Than Pop

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, segue

I'd like to know if it is possible to completely unload a view from my navigation controller.

For example say a user gets to the last view controller then taps Done - i want them to be able to restart as if they were launching the app the first time.

I know i can use the pop methods then setup in ViewDidAppear but i'd like the code in ViewDidLoad to be rerun.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Move the (necessary) code in `viewDidLoad` to `viewWillAppear:`.

You shouldn't necessarily need to do EVERYTHING in `viewDidLoad` every time the view appears.  Anyway, at the end of the day, code that should be executed only the first time the view is loaded should be in `viewDidLoad`.  Code that should be executed every time the view appears should be in `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:`.

Answer (score 0):

Write your code in viewWillAppear method.Another option is if you have time flexibility then **Reload data After Some delay**.Suppose,your view load then After 1 second(any time period) call the method which do reload data.Delay method using you can do reload data.